# I am having trouble declaring a string type in c++.

Tags: c++

I have included  as a header. When I call the string I use std::string to fully specify where string is coming from. The error reads Zach was not declared in this scope. Could it by IDE or Compiler? I use eclipse with g++ on linux Ubuntu.  The following is my source code.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>

     int main(){
     std::string name = Zach;
     std::cout << name << std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: Since this was just the matter of forgetting quote marks, it's best to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a simple syntax error. Zach needed quotation marks around it.